# SQL Server : Hierarchy / Account Level

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchy

I have been battling a bit with building an account hierarchy level structure with SQL and hope someone can assist me.

I can retrieve the levels if I pass one 'highest level' record to a query and bring back the hierarchy levels, but I need to combine this for all records to return a full result set.

I'll show my examples below.

Table structures below:

Main table with the highest level and ID

```
ID      Code
---------------
2341    ACC0070
5689    ACC0590
```

Table with the hierarchy levels

```
Code       Indention    Name
---------------------------------
ACC0010       0         Level 1
ACC0015       1         Level 2
ACC0030       2         Level 3
ACC0065       2         Level 3 
ACC0070       3         Level 4
ACC0155       0         Level 1
ACC0460       1         Level 2
ACC0500       2         Level 3
ACC0585       2         Level 3
ACC0587       3         Level 4
ACC0590       3         Level 4
```

End result should be as follows:

```
ID     Code     Indentation     Name
----------------------------------------
2341   ACC0010       0          Level 1
2341   ACC0015       1          Level 2
2341   ACC0065       2          Level 3
2341   ACC0070       3          Level 4
5689   ACC0155       0          Level 1
5689   ACC0460       1          Level 2
5689   ACC0585       2          Level 3
5689   ACC0590       3          Level 4
```

There will only be 4 levels indicated by the indentation.

Hierarchy levels that must returned will always be the `MAX([Code])` for the previous indentation for any `[Code]` smaller than the highest indentation entry.

Example code that I have if I pass the `[Code]` of an entry with an Indentation of level 3. This will return the correct results for one entry

```
SELECT 
    MAX(RowNr) AS [RowNr], MAX([Code]), Indentation 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Indentation ORDER BY [Code], Indentation DESC) AS [RowNr], 
         [Code], Indentation, [Name]
     FROM 
         <tablename>
     WHERE 
         [Code] <= 'ACC0070') AS res
GROUP BY 
    Indentation
```

So basically the query should be executed for every entry with indentation value of 3 and return the levels for all entries.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT

I can get the desired results with a cursor. Not sure if this will be possible without using a cursor. That would be ideal.

```
-- Cursor Example
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#HierarchyGL') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #HierarchyGL
GO
CREATE TABLE #HierarchyGL
(
    No_ VARCHAR(50),
    [Code] VARCHAR(50),
    [Name] VARCHAR(50)
);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#HierarchyTEST') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #HierarchyTEST
GO
CREATE TABLE #HierarchyTEST
(
    [Dimension Code] VARCHAR(50),
    Code VARCHAR(50),
    [Name] VARCHAR(50),
    Indentation int,
);

-- # INSERT Begin
INSERT INTO #HierarchyGL ([No_],[Code],[Name]) VALUES ('GL1234','ACC0070', 'G L Test Acc 1');
INSERT INTO #HierarchyGL ([No_],[Code],[Name]) VALUES ('GL1235','ACC0587', 'G L Test Acc 2');
INSERT INTO #HierarchyGL ([No_],[Code],[Name]) VALUES ('GL1236','ACC0590', 'G L Test Acc 3');

INSERT INTO #HierarchyTEST ([Dimension Code],Code,[Name],Indentation) VALUES ('GL', 'ACC0010', 'Level 1', 0);
INSERT INTO #HierarchyTEST ([Dimension Code],Code,[Name],Indentation) VALUES ('GL','ACC0015', 'Level 2', 1);
INSERT INTO #HierarchyTEST ([Dimension Code],Code,[Name],Indentation) VALUES ('GL','ACC0030', 'Level 3', 2);
INSERT INTO #HierarchyTEST ([Dimension Code],Code,[Name],Indentation) VALUES ('GL','ACC0035', 'Level 4', 3);
INSERT INTO #HierarchyTEST ([Dimension Code],Code,[Name],Indentation) VALUES ('GL','ACC0065', 'Level 3', 2);
INSERT INTO #HierarchyTEST ([Dimension Code],Code,[Name],Indentation) VALUES ('GL','ACC0070', 'Level 4', 3);
INSERT INTO #HierarchyTEST ([Dimension Code],Code,[Name],Indentation) VALUES ('GL','ACC0155', 'Level 1', 0);
INSERT INTO #HierarchyTEST ([Dimension Code],Code,[Name],Indentation) VALUES ('GL','ACC0460', 'Level 2', 1);
INSERT INTO #HierarchyTEST ([Dimension Code],Code,[Name],Indentation) VALUES ('GL','ACC0500', 'Level 3', 2);
INSERT INTO #HierarchyTEST ([Dimension Code],Code,[Name],Indentation) VALUES ('GL','ACC0585', 'Level 3', 2);
INSERT INTO #HierarchyTEST ([Dimension Code],Code,[Name],Indentation) VALUES ('GL','ACC0587', 'Level 4', 3);
INSERT INTO #HierarchyTEST ([Dimension Code],Code,[Name],Indentation) VALUES ('GL','ACC0590', 'Level 4', 3);
-- # INSERT End

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #results
GO
CREATE TABLE #results
(
    GLAccNo VARCHAR(50),
    GLName VARCHAR(50),
    DimCode VARCHAR(50),
    DimName VARCHAR(50),
    Indentation int
);

DECLARE 
    @gl_no VARCHAR(20), 
    @gl_name VARCHAR(50),
    @dim_code  VARCHAR(50),
    @dim_name VARCHAR(50),
    @indentation int;

DECLARE cursor_hierarchy CURSOR
    FOR SELECT  [No_], gl.Name, hl.Code, hl.Name 
        FROM #HierarchyGL gl
        INNER JOIN #HierarchyTEST hl
        ON gl.Code = hl.Code;

OPEN cursor_hierarchy;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_hierarchy INTO   
    @gl_no,
    @gl_name,
    @dim_code,
    @dim_name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    PRINT @gl_no;

    -- get hierarchy
    INSERT INTO #results 
    SELECT @gl_no, @gl_name, MAX(Code) AS [Code], MAX([Name]), Indentation
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Indentation ORDER BY Code , Indentation DESC) AS RowNr,
            Code, [Dimension Code], Indentation, [Name]
        FROM #HierarchyTEST
        WHERE [Dimension Code] = 'GL'
        AND Code <= @dim_code
    ) AS res
    GROUP BY Indentation

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_hierarchy INTO   
        @gl_no,
        @gl_name,
        @dim_code,
        @dim_name;

END;

CLOSE cursor_hierarchy;
DEALLOCATE cursor_hierarchy;

SELECT * FROM #results;
```

And the result set

```
GLAccNo, GLName, DimCode, DimName, Indentation
GL1234, G L Test Acc 1, ACC0010, Level 1, 0 
GL1234, G L Test Acc 1, ACC0015, Level 2, 1 
GL1234, G L Test Acc 1, ACC0065, Level 3, 2 
GL1234, G L Test Acc 1, ACC0070, Level 4, 3 
GL1235, G L Test Acc 2, ACC0155, Level 1, 0 
GL1235, G L Test Acc 2, ACC0460, Level 2, 1 
GL1235, G L Test Acc 2, ACC0585, Level 3, 2 
GL1235, G L Test Acc 2, ACC0587, Level 4, 3 
GL1236, G L Test Acc 3, ACC0155, Level 1, 0 
GL1236, G L Test Acc 3, ACC0460, Level 2, 1 
GL1236, G L Test Acc 3, ACC0585, Level 3, 2 
GL1236, G L Test Acc 3, ACC0590, Level 4, 3
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  From what I can tell, you are depending on the ordering of the rows for the hierarchy.  You need additional information in the table.

Comment: True, hence the reason for the ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION BY to get the base result set in the correct order. This cannot change, so the records will be in the correct order.